# Output free Memory as single value in Mega Bytes

Tags: powershell, memory-management, powershell-2.0, file-io

i am searching for a solution, i want to get my free memory space as single value in MB.

When i for example out-file it, i always get time stap etc.

for me it doesn't matter wheter we get the result by get-counter or get-wmiobject.

i tried it this way and ofc i always get the full message outfiled...

```
get-wmiobject win32_operatingSystem FreephysicalMemory

Get-Counter -Counter "\Memory\Available MBytes"
```

Thank you in advance!

ray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$mem = Get-Counter -Counter "\Memory\Available MBytes"
$mem.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue
```

or

```
# FreephysicalMemory is represented in kb, devide it in 1kb to get the value in mb
(get-wmiobject win32_operatingSystem FreephysicalMemory).FreePhysicalMemory/1kb
```